# How do I clear IE's cache when running Web Developer Express?

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, caching

I'm trying to debug some IE-only issues for a site I'm developing.  I'm running WDE because there's no Firebug for IE.  I want to see whether some changes fix a bug, but no matter what I do, IE never picks up my changes.  I've tried all of the following:

- stopping and restarting the debug evnironment
- closing and re-opening WDE
- closing and re-opening IE
- clearing IE's "temporary internet files"
- swearing at Microsoft for building such awful software

Any help?  Are there some cached files somewhere on the drive I could clear out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE Developer Toolbar has *"Clear Browser Cache ..."* and *"Clear Browser Cache for This Domain ..."* menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ctrl+f5?  It reloads the current page and clears the cache.  If even after that your changes don't propagate, the problems in your code.

Comment: Tried that.  There's no code; it's just an HTML page.  And it refreshes fine in FF.

Comment: Like Gaius, I've had trouble with Ctrl+F5 not working, so now I use IE Toolbar.  If anyone knows the difference between IE Toolbar's "Clear Browser Cache" and Ctrl+F5, please post.  (Are they supposed to work the same?)

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function (e)
{
  if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY)
  {
    window.applicationCache.swapCache();
    if (confirm('A new version of this site is available. Load it?'))
     window.location.reload();
  }
}, false);
```

I found this solution somwhere in the Net. Sorry, but I don't remember the author.
It works for me when I debug Web App with JavaScript in IE.